# What's the best way to convert cookie string to an object

Tags: javascript, cookies

Actually I have a simple implementation to do that but I'd like to know if there any other ways to do achieve the same result.

```
const cookiesToObject = cookies => {
  const result = {};
  const cookiesArray = cookies.split('; ');

  cookiesArray.forEach(cookie => {
    const cookieArray = cookie.split('=');

    result[cookieArray[0]] = cookieArray[1];
  });

  return result;
};

const cookies = 'name=Jon; surname=Jons; age=30';

console.log(cookiesToObject(cookies));
```

Comment: i always use jQuery cookie for this, I'm sure there is a light lib to help you with this: check js-cookie

Comment: @31piy, thank you for answer, but it looks like the same solution that I have

Comment: Using reduce like: `cookies.split('; ').reduce((r, v, i, a) => { const k = v.split('='); r[k[0]] = k[1]; return r; }, {})`